# If x tends to 0,then what does cx tend to where c is a constant?

Tags: calculus

I saw in a math solution that $\lim_{x\to0}(1+2x)^{\frac{1}{2x}(10)}=e^{10}$.But here we are using $x$ tends to $0$ but not $2x$ tends to $0$. Does that mean when $x$ tends to $0$ then $cx$ tends to $0$ when $c$ is a constant? If so, why?

Thanks.

Comment: So your real question is: "Why is $\lim_{x\to 0} cx =0$ when $c$ is a constant?". Well, think about the definition of a limit. Then it's quite easy to show that ...

Comment: Why not? For c>0, see if x<1 then cx<c, if x<1/c then cx<1, if x<1/c^2 then cx<1/c, ifx<1/c^n then cx<1/c^n-1. What I am saying is when x goes to 0 then cx als goes to zero.

Comment: Matti P. Please show the process,actually i am just new to calculus,so things are a bit hazy for me to understand

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $x\rightarrow 0$ then $cx\rightarrow 0$ too since $c$ is a constant. We have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}cx=c\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x=c\cdot0=0$ for any $c\in\mathbb R$. See [here](https://www.math24.net/properties-limits/) for properties of limits.

Indeed setting $y=2x$ then we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\big(1+2x\big)^{\frac{10}{2x}}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\big(1+y\big)^{\frac{10}{y}}$$
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\big[\big(1+y\big)^{\frac{1}{y}}\big]^{10}$$
$$=\big[\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\big(1+y\big)^{\frac{1}{y}}\big]^{10}=e^{10}$$

by the power rule where we have $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\big(1+y\big)^{\frac{1}{y}}=e$